# Complete list of steps to migrate live website from one server to another

Tags: mysql, apache, web, migration

I'm preparing to launch a new version of an existing website. The new site will be on a completely separate server that uses a LAMP setup. Here's my plan:

1. Set up the new site on the new server
2. Rsync user-generated content to new server
3. Take down the old site
4. Take a snapshot of the old MySQL database and load it on the new server
5. Rsync user-generated content again
6. Bring up the new site
7. Point the DNS to the new server

**Am I forgetting anything? Is there a better way of doing this that avoids downtime (or minimizes it)?**

I purposely didn't provide many details about my specific setup because I'd like a list of steps that is fairly generic and can be followed for most migrations. If that doesn't work or if there are details that you need to know to provide a better answer, I'll be happy to add them.

Comment: How much downtime can you tolerate?

Comment: Avoid the DNS transfer if you can. That is going to cause you serious downtime. If your box is hosted on the same network just transfer the IP, setup routing at the switch, physically move the plug, etc.

Comment: In this case, almost as much downtime as I want (over an hour or two would be bad). But I'd like to know the proper way to do this, i.e. on a site that is in constant use and depends on traffic for money.

Comment: The box is not on the same network. It's not even on the same hosting site. But that's a good idea. How long do DNS changes take to propogate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that it's only going to take a couple of hours, I would point the DNS first as it can take up to and over 6 hours to propogate. You can always change the host file on your workstation to point to the new IP address in the mean time.

Other than that I can't think of anything else.

How come you're moving servers? Have you run out of space?

Comment: We're taking over management of a site and their servers are old and slow, so they are paying us to move to a better machine. Changing the DNS ahead of time is a good idea, though it looks like GoDaddy makes the change instantly.

Comment: GoDaddy might make the change instantly, but you've still got the other DNS servers around the world that have cached your settings and will probably take a good while to change.

Comment: Also, the reason why I asked about the size of the servers is to question whether you've thought about some kind of cloud offering like rackspace cloud's cloud servers. That way, if you do start to run out of space you can easily just scale up the servers as and when you need to and you don't have to worry about moving things.

Comment: I have thought about using something cloud-based, but the prices are too high compared to the server we have now and we're not hitting any limits on our server yet. I know I'll have to move to something bigger eventually, but I'd rather put that off.

Comment: Have you had a look at the prices? Rackspace cloud servers (not sites) are fairly reasonable.